# Bind or marge or dock the conetnt of sub form into the main form

Tags: c#, forms, bind, mdi, dock

I have system where from the main from will generate some sub forms.

My point, when the user need to merge the child information on the main form, to see the child form as part of main form.

Such like many system, when view sub window, then it is possible to dock or bind this sub window onto the main window.

How to do that? On other hand, I have some space in the main form to Dock the child in it.

I mean such like this:
1- generate stand alone window(sub) from main

[image]

2- when user drag this sub from to the main,it will be merge into the main window:

[image]

Comment: Are you using MDI or non MDI?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, you're not using non MDI form. Unless I misunderstood you can set `TopLevel` to false, and add the child to any parent.

```
MyChildForm child = new MyChildForm();
child.TopLevel = false;//Important
parent.Controls.Add(child);
child.Visible = true;
```

Comment: thank you for help,
but it is my fault, I need for stand alone form not child ones
could you see my edit to the question, Please.

Comment: @Hana90 Code I provided will work, `MyChildForm` is just a name, it can be whatever. It can be a standalone form as you said. You'll have to work on the dragging part though. More likely you're looking for a [DockPanel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) I guess

Comment: yes your code worked, but I want to generate the form as above stand alone then can bind it into the main.
thanks for the Dock library, but how can I get its tutorial?

Comment: I hope google can help you in this. I have never used it. here is the [source](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite), you can download and check the code. Check the DockSample project.

Comment: Thank you, I try to find solution